# Chrome pausing debugger on exceptions

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I am using Chrome `Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on Windows 10.
During debug I have unchecked **Pause on caught exceptions**[image]

But most probably this exception is uncaught, therefore the debugger keep stopping there. It is very annoying.

Is there a way to disable debugger stop on all kinds of exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I found my mistake:
I have mistakenly activated this button:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, had exactly the same issue :D